# Git can overwrites files owned by root (no sudo)

Tags: linux, git

I have a Git folder which has files owned by me ("francois") and files owned by "root".

For the record: the files owned by roots are linked into `/etc/network/if-up.d` to be executed by root when the network is activated at startup. So that would be dangerous if I let access to these to standard users.

When I `git commit` these files are blocking, as expected, so I did `sudo git commit`.
But `git pull` or `git checkout` have no problem taking control on theses files and even change the owner.

Here's an example with `git checkout`:

```sh
francois@computer:~/appli_bash$ sudo chown root app_times_update.sh

francois@computer:~/appli_bash$ sudo chmod 700 app_times_update.sh

francois@computer:~/appli_bash$ ll
blabla…
-rwx------  1 root       dreamtroic 5988 févr.  3 18:43 app_times_update.sh*
blabla…

francois@computer:~/appli_bash$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app_times_update.sh

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

francois@computer:~/appli_bash$ git checkout app_times_update.sh

francois@computer:~/appli_bash$ ll
blabla…
-rwxrwxr-x  1 francois francois 5988 févr.  3 18:44 app_times_update.sh*
blabla…
```

And I made a similar observation when I `git pull`.

I figured out that Git actually doesn't "see" the `chown`, only the `chmod`… but that does not really explain how Git can overcome the root ownership. Isn't it a security issue?

Also if you have any suggestion to better organize my work (this experience suggests I should do so), I would be happy to read it.

Thank you!

Comment: Have some `make install` step that only `root` could run. Take inspiration from the build of [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) from source code. Consider using [install(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/install.1.html)

Comment: I'm sorry: I pasted the result of the `ll` I did after the `chown` not the `chmod`. I edited my post.  
  
One a side note, even with the 775 permissions, one cannot change the owner without `sudo` (I've just cheked).

Comment: Also, in order to *remove* a file, you only need write permissions on the directory that contains the file. Simply removing write permissions from the file itself is not sufficient.

Comment: Don't comment own question, but [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66033628/edit) it!

Comment: This is not specific to Git: `touch foo; sudo chmod root foo; sudo chmod 700 foo; rm foo`. `rm` will ask you to override the permissions, rather than immediately removing the file, but it will succeed.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I was commenting an answer that disappeared and it became an comment of your answer, which is indeed confusing.

The original question mentioned the fact that my file had 755 permissions. That was a typo and I edited my question.

Comment: Notice that `git` uses, like all Linux applications, the Linux system calls. These are documented in [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what is happening. Also  **[git](https://git-scm.com/) is *open source* software**, you are allowed to study its source code, and you could recompile it (with `gcc -Wall -g`) and use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand its behavior

Comment: @chepner I did not realize there also was a problem with removing the file… but my question was about `chown` which is normally not possible: `touch foo; sudo chown root foo; sudo chmod 700 foo; chown $USER foo`

Comment: That's because Git isn't using `chown`; it's removing the file first, then creating a new one using the contents from the repository. Git itself has virtually no concept of file permissions. The files it creates on checkout are either 644 or 755 (depending on whether the file is executable or not), owned by the current user and group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout` only does one thing with the existing file: it *removes* it, for which it only requires write permissions for the current directory.

After the file is remove, Git *creates* a new file owned by the current user and its default group, with 755 permissions if the tracked file is executable, 644 otherwise.

Comment: Nice now I understand your first remark. Thank you!